Transitive, effective, but not free $S_n$ actions
I want to figure out all "interesting" $S_n$ actions. It is well known standart $S_n$ action: $$S_n\curvearrowright \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}: (\sigma, x) \longmapsto \sigma(x).$$ This action is transitive, effective and not free. My question is, are there any other actions of $S_n$ with such conditions? If such actions exist, then can they act on sets of size less than n?
P. S. I know about $S_4\curvearrowright V_4 \backslash \{e\}: (\sigma, v) \longmapsto \sigma v$, so let $n>4$.

What does "effective" mean? Is it the same as faithful?

The action you've listed for $V_4$ is not an action, you probably mean conjugation (and so it's not effective). This problem is probably more tractable by using the fact transitive actions correspond to coset actions on subgroups (the subgroup being a point stabilizer). Being effective then means this subgroup is core-free (contains no nontrivial normal subgroup). Being free means the subgroup is the identity. So you're looking for subgroups of $S_n$ that don't contain a normal subgroup, and there are lots of those.

As for "size less than $n$", that's not possible. A transitive effective action on $m$ elements gives an embedding of $S_n$ into $S_m$.

I assume "effective" means "faithful." There are many such actions: for a natural class of examples, $S_n$ naturally acts on the set of $k$-element subsets of $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$, which we might notate ${[n] \choose k}$. This action is always transitive, and it's faithful for $1 \le k \le n-1$ except maybe for some small values of $n$ and $k$ ($n = 4, k = 2$ might be troublesome or it might be fine). Similarly we can consider the action of $S_n$ on the set of partitions of $[n]$ into a collection of subsets of some fixed sizes.
As Steve D says in the comments, transitive actions correspond to actions on cosets $S_n/G$ for some subgroup $G$ (the stabilizer of some point). The kernel of this action is the intersection $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma G \sigma^{-1}$ of the conjugates of $G$, so faithful transitive actions correspond to subgroups $G$ such that this intersection is trivial, and they're free if $G$ is trivial. For $n \ge 5$ the simplicity of $A_n$ implies that this intersection, which is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, must be either trivial, $A_n$, or $S_n$, so as long as $G$ is strictly smaller than $A_n$, this intersection is always trivial for $n \ge 5$. This means there are many, many, many possibilities in general, we can take $G$ to be a nearly arbitrary subgroup of $S_n$. These in turn are classified by faithful actions of arbitrary finite groups $G$ on sets of size $n$!

If such actions exist, then can they act on sets of size less than n?

No. By definition if $S_n$ acts faithfully on a set of size $k$ then this gives an injection of $S_n$ into $S_k$, which of course forces $k \ge n$ by comparing cardinalities. For $n \ge 5$ we can replace "faithfully" with "acts with nonabelian image" by the simplicity of $A_n$.
